# React.js iframe src

Tags: reactjs, iframe

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Outside iFrame</h1>
                <iframe title="myiframe" src="./target.html" width="600px" height="400px"></iframe>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

index.html

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

target.html

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <h1>Inside IFrame</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

the Problem is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N621.png)

what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this issue because the relative url `src="./target.html"` is incorrect. To make sure you are using the correct url, please individually check the url generated for index.html and target.html. Also make sure that you are not making a typo error.

I tried running your code and it works fine if your target.html and index.html urls are as follows :

[image: target.html]

[image: index.html]

I can also recreate your issue, if I make a typo error in my code like so `src="./typoerror.html"` ,

[image: Typo error case]

Comment: thanks, i use the wrong url , because i put the index.html in Public File,but my index.js in Src File. the url must be according to the index.html File Path

Comment: Any idea why we are seeing nested iframes if there is a wrong url for the iframe src?